# javascript: send POST with audio file and then redirect to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, audio

Here is what I have.

./upload > upload existing local audio file to ./post_receiver by POST request

./post_receiver > receive POST request and respond a HTML page

./record > record an audio file to be either downloaded to local or uploaded to ./post_receiver by AJAX POST request

They are working fine, but I don't want to use AJAX though. I prefer a new HTML page. I know how to use traditional form by document.createElement("form"), document.body.appendChild(), and submit(). But, it seems it cannot hold audio file like FormData does. By the way, my server is node.js on Amazon EC2, but I think it is not related.

Non-AJAX POST from ./record

```
<form method="POST" action="/audio" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="audio" value="blob:address" filename="audio.wav">
</form>

    Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
        at router.get.html (./routes/index.js:11:74)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (./node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
        at Object.<anonymous> (./node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:52:37)
        at Object.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:348:16)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

------WebKitFormBoundaryxh3BZE3s5vvxVQ1n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryxh3BZE3s5vvxVQ1n--
```

AJAX POST from ./record or POST from ./upload

```
<form action="/audio" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="audio" required="">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

------WebKitFormBoundary47iCp5HAMwe089e4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="audio.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav


------WebKitFormBoundary47iCp5HAMwe089e4--
```

The following trick works, but it is still on the same page, which is not what I want.

```
document.open();
document.write(<XMLHttpRequest>.responseText);
document.close();
```

Also, something like socket/stream/session/cookies is kind of overkill. I just want to keep it simple, and I hope there is a way to send FormData as a request and let the browser to directly process the respond from the server. If this is not possible, then please let me know a simple way to achieve this.

Appreciate any idea and suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what I ended up doing. I changed my POST handler from returning a redirect to returning a response with the redirect URL in the body. Then I just did this (instead of the writing to the document trick):

```
redirectURL = <XMLHttpRequest>.responseText;
window.location = redirectURL;
```